# Different font sizes in the same annotation of matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, font-size, treemap, plot-annotations

I need to annotate a pylab rectangle with few data lines - which are of *different* length.
Searching through the matplotlib documentation, and Googling, I could not find a way to give different parts of an annotation different sizes.

The following snippet demonstrates the problem:

```py
import pylab
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
pylab.rcParams['verbose.level'] = 'debug-annoying' 

def draw_rectangle(lower, upper, entry):
    ax = pylab.subplot(111)
    r = Rectangle( lower, upper[0]-lower[0], upper[1] - lower[1],
            edgecolor='k')
    ax.add_patch(r)

    textRank = str(entry['rank'])
    textTeamName = entry['teamName']
    textSubmissionDate = entry['submissionDate']
    text = textRank + "\n" + textTeamName + "\n" + textSubmissionDate

    ax.add_artist(r)
    rx, ry = r.get_xy()
    cx = rx + r.get_width()/2.0
    cy = ry + r.get_height()/2.0

    ax.annotate(text, (cx, cy), color='w', weight='bold', ha='center', va='center', size=14)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    entry = {'rank': 22, 'submissionDate': '12/21/2012 4:58:45 AM', 'teamName': 'A very very very very very very very very very very long name'}
    lower = [0,0]
    upper = [1,1]
    draw_rectangle(lower, upper, entry)
    pylab.show()
```

[image: one rectangle with different length's data]

E.g., is there a way to have the annotation where the font size of 'teamName' is different than the font size of 'rank'?

*Another problem* is I could not find a way for the font size to correlate to the zooming:

I'm creating a treemap plot, namely, the pylab window is filled with different sized rectangles. If I want to create annotations for the different rectangles, the long data need to be of very small size (to stay within the respective rectangles' boundaries). However, I'd like the font size of the long data line to **grow** as I zoom in.

[image: treemap with annotations]

Answer (score 54):

Make your plot first, then use `ax.annotate`, iterating over your x coordinates, y coordinates, labels and fontsizes.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [1,2,3,4,5]
Y = [1,1,1,1,1]
labels = 'ABCDE'
sizes = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(X, Y)

for x, y, label, size in zip(X, Y, labels, sizes):
    ax.annotate(label, (x, y), fontsize=size)

plt.show()
```

[image: plot with varying font sizes]

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find a way to create an annotation with different fonts, so I'll create a helper function that will calculate the font weight to use on each line of the annotation, with the relevant (cx, cy), 
and then call ax.annotate several times.

Comment: Would you share it ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Annotations are stored in `ax.texts`, which is a list of Annotation objects. Annotation objects define a `set_size()` method, which can be called if the fontsize of a specific annotation needs to be changed *after* the plot is made.

This is especially useful if the plot with the annotations are created using an external library such as scikit-learn, statsmodels etc.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, Y, labels = [1,2,3,4,5], [1]*5, 'ABCDE'
sizes = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30]

# scatter plot with annotations
plt.scatter(X, Y)
for x, y, label in zip(X, Y, labels):
    plt.annotate(label, (x, y))

# change annotation fontsizes
ax = plt.gca()
for a, size in zip(ax.texts, sizes):
    a.set_size(size)
```

[image: result]